# TFS and SharePoint are slower after upgrading to TFS2010 & SharePoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, tfs, migration

We've recently upgraded (migration path) from TFS/Sharepoint to TFS2010/Sharepoint2010.

Most things went well, but there were a few issues that became immediately apparent.

1. TFS was noticeably slower (as pointed out by the entire dev team). Basically all "get latest", and query operations were more sluggish. Starting VS2010 SP1 is also really slow with loading all the projects (40+) on my machine. A refresh after that is not normally a problem. Even though other people may only have 3-4 projects open at the time, they too noticed the "working..." delay.
2. Sharepoint was definitely *much* slower. The "Show Portal" takes forever to load, and the basic editing is slower too.
3. Work items occasionally "time out" for no reason, and end up in a "connection lost" error. It's normally while creating a new work item, and a redo of the same command works fine. It happens even during bulk work item creation, but the timing is random.

The server runs on Windows 2008, 12 GB, and plenty of CPU power (QuadCore). The IIS connectionTimeout is set to 2 minutes (default), I've played with the `MinBytesPerSecond` which is set to 240 by default (I've set it to 42 as well, but no joy), and I understand that VS 2010 in general might be a bit slower than its 2008 counterpart, but even then. No processors are maxed out. There are lots of MSSQLSERVER info logs in the Event Viewer though (I just noticed this - not sure if this is a problem). I've also changed the `defaultProxy` setting in the `devenv.exe` file - no joy there either.

It's too late for a downgrade. ;)

Has anyone experienced similar problems after the upgrade?

I would love to hear from ya! :o)

Comment: You might want to consider serverfault.com as stackoverflow is mostly about programming related questions.

Comment: On #3 - how long before work items "time out"? Is it a round-number like 30 seconds, or 5 minutes?

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose precisely, but it looks like you may have either a network problem or a SQL problem. How does the configuration compare to the pre-upgrade environment? Are there any extra routers/firewalls/load-balancers/proxies in the mix? Did you change SQL servers as well?

Comment: Timeouts were random. I'm not aware how far apart they were. One thing I found out yesterday was that when I changed MinBytesPerSecond back to 240, errors popped up continuously. I've since set it back to 10, but haven't heard back yet.

Comment: I think both configurations were pretty similar. The old computer was Win2003 with maybe 4-8 GB RAM on it. I've asked the network guys about why it could be so slow, and they didn't know either. At a guess I'd say they were in similar conditions as the new computer.

Answer (score 1):

We experienced performance issues after upgrading from TFS 2008 to 2010 but it is much better now. We have learned that the Antivirus and SQL Server configurations are critical. In a virtualized environment store performance is key too. We have about 100 TFS users in a 2 tier Server setup.

The SQL server has it's default memory setting set as follows:
1 - SQL Server max memory 2TB
2 - Analysis Services max memory 100%

With those settings, our 8GB SQL machine was unusable.

Now we have:
1 - SQL Server max memory 4GB
2 - Analysis Server Max memory 15%

Now the performance is ok but not great.

The Antivirus Exclusions have to configured too. Basically excluded all the data and temp directories.

As our TFS setup is virtualized we are in the process of adding more storage hardware to have better disk performance. That should definitely solve our performance issues.

Simon

Comment: The fact that SQL Server does its own memory management can be very tricky if it needs to share hardware with other processes. I've also limited the available cores to SQL in the past, so that it couldn't take the whole server down. If you have a quad or more core (especially with Hyperthreading), this might be a trick to try as well.

Comment: Since my first post, we've now increased the memory to 32 GB, but it didn't make much any difference. I think the machine itself is just very slow (or sluggish). After discussing this with our network administrator, we were assured we had the latest hardware, but the whole thing runs on a virtual machine. I wasn't aware of that. It doesn't share any CPU/disk with other virtual machines, but still. Sometimes a backup starts during work hours which isn't helping. I will investigate the Antivirus comment. I've also suggested going back to a native computer, but I don't think it will happen. ;)

Comment: And oh yeah, the same machine runs TFS, Sharepoint, and SQL, but we are considering migrating Sharepoint to another machine.

Answer (score 0):

are all components installed on one machine? Is SQL layer also installed on that machine? Is the machine virtualized?

It's always better to install SQL layer on physical hardware than installing it virtually. SharePoint 2010 requires 4 gigs of RAM. To ensure that SharePoint is usable you should size the WFE with at least 8 gigs of RAM.

Our TFS was also slow with 4 gigs so I've added another 4 gigs. With this setup the entire environment is right now really fast.

Let's summarize

- SQL: physical installation w/ 12GB RAM, Quad Core (duplicated for failover)
- SharePoint: virtualized w/ 8GB RAM, Quad Core
- TFS: virtualized w/ 8GB RAM, Quad Core

Both SharePoint and TFS are generating heavy load on the database. I've a showcase machine running on my Elitebook as HyperV image. The image has about 12 gigs of ram and is running on an external SSD but it is a lot slower than our productive environment.

I hope my thoughts and setups are helpful.

Thorsten

Comment: Yep, all on one server. It's not virtualized as far as I'm aware. We had some memory problems in the beginning. I was rather surprised to find it was only equipped with 4 GB (especially once you hear the price of the machine). We almost immediately upgraded it to 8 GB, that was definitely better, but still not very good, so I requested 64 GB just to be sure, but only got 12 GB total. It's also my understanding that the SQL server will use up all the available memory (looks that way). Could that be the problem? Certainly appreciate your feedback. Thanks.